# Give an example of $k$-iso-regular for $k \ge 2$

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory, graph-isomorphism

A graph is said to be $k$-isoregular if for every subset $S$ of at most $k$ vertices the number common neighbors of the elements of $S$ depends only on the isomorphism type of the subgraph induced by $S$. I need an example of $k$-isoregular, where $k \ge 2$. The below given graph is not an valid example, see $\{4,14\}$ and $\{4,5\}$. Thanks in the advance.

[image]

Comment: You asked me a question at https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2440226, then you deleted it before I could answer, so I'll answer here. You asked, "Isn't this website supoposed to help people?" Well, I did help you – I answered your question. You thought my answer was incorrect, so I explained in detail why it was not incorrect. You ignored this, so I asked you whether my answer was correct. You ignored this, too. If you can't be bothered to pay attention to your own question, you can't be very interested in the question, it shouldn't bother you that one person voted to close it.

Comment: And, anyway, what's the difference between the question you ask here, and the one you deleted? And what's wrong with the answer from Jorge? Why are you not engaging with Jorge concerning his answer? What kind of game are you playing, anyway? Post the same question twice, dispute correct answers both times, and walk away from further discussion – why would you do that?

Comment: @Gerry Myerson I have undelete the post so that you will be able to see the difference. Both question are differ by a term called  " PLANARITY" AND THERE IS ONE MORE TERM KNOWN AS DEGREE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally, any strongly regular graph satisfies the condition with $k=2$. For an example, consider the cycle $C_5$, or the Petersen Graph.

Comment: Strong regularity is equivalent to $2$-iso-regular you defined.

Comment: @nwaaa The definition means that $k$-iso-regular implies $k-1$-iso-regular.  So strong regularity will always be there. For examples with $k\geq 3$, there is the folded 5-cube(with $k=3$) or the [Schlafli graph](http://www.win.tue.nl/~aeb/graphs/Schlaefli.html)(with $k=4$).

Answer (score 2):

The regular complete $r$-multipartite graph $K_{n,n,\dots,n}$ is $k$-complete for all $k$.

The only way in which $S$ has common elements is if the $k$ elements are in different classes and then the number of common elements is $n(r-k)$.

For a much simpler example consider the empty and complete graphs.

Comment: your definition only talks about the number of common neiighbours, which is the same if the multipartite graph is regular.

Comment: yes, I understand that. The examples still work.